# How can I save past high scores?

Tags: python

I currently have this code for a high scores list:

```
scores = []
choice = None
while choice != "0":
    print(
    """
    High Scores
    0 - Quit
    1 - List Scores
    2 - Add a Score
    """
    )
    choice = input("Choice: ")
    print()
    if choice == "0":
        print("Goodbye")
    elif choice == "1":
        print("High Scores\n")
        print("NAME\tSCORE")
        for entry in scores:
            score, name = entry
            print(name, "\t", score)
    elif choice == "2":
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        score = int(input("What score did you get? "))
        entry = [score, name]
        scores.append(entry)
        scores.sort(reverse=True)
        scores = scores[:10]
    else:
        print("Sorry, but", choice, "isn't a valid choice.")
```

Can anyone tell me how to add code in which will save the high score for next time the program is used

Comment: For that you will have to save it to some file/database

Comment: try [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module, very simple to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json

def load_scores():
    with open("scores.json") as infile:
        return json.load(infile)

def save_scores(scores):
    with open("scores.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(scores, outfile)
```

Now you can call `save_scores(scores)` to save the current highscore list, and do `scores = load_scores()` to get them back from the file.

Comment: Does that just get put in anywhere or does it need to be in a specific place?

Comment: Well, the block of code above should go at the top level of your program. If you create a file called `scores.json` that contains nothing but `[]` and place it in the same directory as your script, then you can replace the line `scores = []` with `scores = load_scores()`. The call to `save_scores` would make most sense as the last line of your script.

Comment: All sorted. Thanks for the help